# Error: no primary server found in set

Tags: mongodb, database-cluster, database

I have a two node cluster...one primary and one secondary. I keep randomly this message

**Error:** `no primary server found in set`

Any suggestions ? In the replica set options I have set it to following :

```
{"read":"secondary", "auto_reconnect":true, safe: true}
```

I am also using newer drivers

```
"mongodb": "1.2.13"

"mongoskin": "0.5.0"
```

Is it because it is just two nodes ? Should I increase number of nodes will that stop these
random read failures ?

Comment: It's not recommended to have a even number of servers in a replica set, because with the default configs they'll not be able to handle who's primary and who's not.
Also, can you edit your post and include how are the members configured?

Answer (score 0):

You will need (at least) three members in your replica set. You should always have an odd number of members in your replica set because, if your primary goes down, the other members vote to see who will be the new primary.

If there are an even number of voters, you will always have a tie and you'll never be able to vote in a new primary.

Comment: this is not correct - you won't have a tie. You just won't have enough votes to elect a new primary.

Answer (score 0):

While 2 nodes isn't recommended for production environments, you can leave the two you have an add a third node that's an *Arbiter* (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replica-sets/#replica-set-arbiters) -- this'll give you an odd number of votes (although an arbiter doesn't actually have any data stored, its sole existence is to vote and avoid a situation where no one has majority of votes in an election).